# '--window-size=' not working with ChromeDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I can't seem to get the '--window-size=' switch working for ChromeDriver for Selenium. Any ideas? Just trying to randomize the window size.

```
from selenium import webdriver

TEST_URL = 'http://localhost:8000'

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_argument('--window-size=1920x1080')
options.add_argument("disable-gpu")
options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])
options.add_experimental_option('w3c', False)
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36")
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', options=options)
```

Answer (score 2):

--window-size argument does not seem to work in Python Selenium.
You can use set_window_size.

```
driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
```

Call this right after creating browser.